# Writing Pyspark Dataframe to TFrecords file

Tags: tensorflow, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe with schema, and want to convert this into tfRecords

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- col3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- col4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: float (containsNull = true)
 |-- col5: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: float (containsNull = true)
 |-- col6: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- col7: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- col8: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- col9: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I'm using spark tensorflow connector

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("tfrecords").option("recordType", "Example").save("targetpath.tf")
```

Error which I'm getting while saving the data into tfrecords

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps
```

I have tried similar approach in databricks community edition as well , also got the similar erro

Can anyone help here ?

Comment: can you specify the reference for ` similar approach in databricks community edition`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable cause (judging from [Maven Central information](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tensorflow/spark-tensorflow-connector)) is that you're using connector compiled for Scala 2.11 on the Databricks runtime that uses Scala 2.12.

Either you need to use DBR 6.4 for that conversion, or [compile connector for Scala 2.12](https://github.com/tensorflow/ecosystem/tree/master/spark/spark-tensorflow-connector#usage-examples) & use.

Comment: you're right changing the version from 2.11 to 2.12 worked, reference jars links for reference - https://search.maven.org/search?q=spark-tfrecord